# Run Windows 7 in VirtualBox on Linux

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have a dual-boot system, Linux Mint and Windows 7. I'd like to continue dual-booting, but preferentially run Linux - however, I still must have Outlook as a mail client. Rather than reinstall Windows after making a VM in VirtualBox, I'd like to use the existing Windows partition as my machine. What I've read is a couple of years old and mentions plenty of problems, meaning re-registering Windows at every boot, conflicting hardware profiles, and a few others. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do the same thing with a Macbook via VMware Fusion and experienced the same issues you read about.  Windows pitches a fit at every boot about the hardware being so different.  I don't recommend it. I would recommend either finding an Outlook replacement, or just never booting to Windows and *only* running it from that partition through VirtualBox.